# Submit a python script in the background via html

Tags: python, html, ajax, cgi

As of now, I have a python script which is fully functional and is run via an `HTML` page with a form input, which then is submitted to the python script using `CGI`.

The problem is that if there is a lot of data, the script can take a long time to finish.

I have changed the apache timeout to be much longer than normal as a temporary workaround, but ultimately what I want to do is have the user submit their data but this time with their email address. Then instead of staring at a white screen for what may potentially be hours, they are directed to a page which informs them that their job has been submitted and the server is crunching the numbers and will email the user back with a url to download their results once their job is completed.

In my scouring of the internet I read that doing this via `CGI` is impossible. The only way that I can think of, though I'm not sure if it's possible/correct, is to try to submit the user's input to the python script via an `AJAX` request, and have the python script run and output to some temporary file. I am not so sure how to check if the job completed successfully/unsuccessfully.

Does anyone know a good way of doing what I described or what it is called?

Comment: So your script returns a large dataset? Is that why it takes so long? Or it just takes a while and you want an asynchronous notification of completion?

Comment: It takes a while and returns a good deal of data but its not beyond the order of megabytes

Comment: No answers? Anyone? :(

Comment: Why not put the returned data into a .zip archive, and email it to the the user. Ofcourse, you will need a html form to accept the email address, if you don't already have it.

Comment: This is a very general problem and not entirely suitable for SO. It sounds like you want to create 3 services on the backend. One to kick off some sort of script, one to poll for its completeness and another to download the results. You could design the download service to download in chunks rather than all in one go. On the front end, use Javascript (AJAX) to call the services.